# gulp-copy - unexpected behavior

Tags: asynchronous, gulp, synchronous

With gulp I want to copy some files from one place to an other before I process them. To demonstrate my problem I've created the following gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var copy = require('gulp-copy');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.start('copy', 'list');
});

gulp.task('copy', function () {   // copy files
    gulp.src('source/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target'));
});

gulp.task('list', function () {   // list all copies files
    gulp.src('target/*')
       .pipe(debug({title: 'file:'}));
});
```

Now, when I run gulp I get the following output:

```
testing [master●●●] % gulp
[20:34:57] Using gulpfile ~/WebstormProjects/testing/gulpfile.js
[20:34:57] Starting 'default'...
[20:34:57] Starting 'copy'...
[20:34:57] Finished 'copy' after 4.92 ms
[20:34:57] Starting 'list'...
[20:34:57] Finished 'list' after 1.84 ms
[20:34:57] Finished 'default' after 7.77 ms
[20:34:57] file: 0 items
```

As you can see the list task doesn't see any files in the `target` directory. Now when I run the task again the last 2 lines are:

```
[20:35:00] file: target/copyme
[20:35:00] file: 1 items
```

As you can see in the first log, the `copy` task starts and finishes before the `list` tasks continues. However, because the list task doesn't see any files in the `target` directory I assume somehow the copy task is async. Any suggestions how I can make it synchronous here ?

For those who want to reproduce, here is my `package.json`

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.8.11",
        "gulp-copy": "0.0.2",
        "gulp-debug": "^2.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use gulp's built in dependency management?

```javascript
var gulp = require('gulp');
var copy = require('gulp-copy');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');

gulp.task('default', ['list']);

gulp.task('copy', function () {   // copy files
    return gulp.src('source/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('target'));
});

gulp.task('list', ['copy'], function () {   // list all copies files
    return gulp.src('target/*')
       .pipe(debug({title: 'file:'}));
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, it gives the same result, output is identical

Comment: Sorry, forgot the return statements, they are very important. They let gulp know when a task is finished.

Comment: interesting, that did the trick! I thought that if you omit the `return` the task is synchronous, but I guess that is not completely true?!

Comment: Technically all tasks are asynchronous. Gulp just ensures that all dependencies are finished before starting dependent tasks.